как деплоить шаблон на nextjs чтобы его потом развернуть на сервере
Уважаемые Коллеги,
Подскажите пожалуйста,после скачивания темы админа на nextjs от sneat, у меня возникла проблема как его деплоить, после того как я проделал определеные действия от в папке next ряд папок и файл build_id и я немогу понять что с этим файлом делать?
Буду очень презнателен.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Вопрос в том, что при команды npm build все файлы собираются в папке next, после команды npm start  появляеться страница логина и стоят рандомные данные для входа, но после нажатие логин он выдает 401 ошибку, и дальше не могу пройти, это первый вариант, второй вариант - добавить в config все эти файлы собирались в папке dist, потом команду npm start и он выдает ошибку сервера, подскажите как настроить правильно чтобы у меня статические файла и я смог открыть их на локальном сервере. За ранее спасибо))
